# Hide a div class on WordPress ID (Based on template)

Tags: css

Really not sure why I am struggling here but I am trying to hide this div:

```
<div class="qodef-post-info-category"> content here which I want to HIDE on this template only </div>
```

I thought that this would work but no joy

```
    body.single-doctor.qodef-post-info-category { 
     display: none; 
}
```

This is the WordPress body tag meta info:

```
<body class="doctor-template-default single single-doctor postid-4633 qode-core-1.1.1 blush child-child-ver-1.0.1 blush-ver-1.3 qodef-smooth-page-transitions qodef-smooth-page-transitions-fadeout qodef-grid-1100 qodef-sticky-header-on-scroll-down-up qodef-dropdown-default qodef-header-standard qodef-menu-area-shadow-disable qodef-menu-area-in-grid-shadow-disable qodef-menu-area-border-disable qodef-menu-area-in-grid-border-disable qodef-logo-area-border-disable qodef-logo-area-in-grid-border-disable qodef-side-menu-slide-from-right qodef-default-mobile-header qodef-sticky-up-mobile-header wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-6.0.5 vc_responsive" itemscope itemtype="//schema.org/WebPage">
```

It has to be hidden per TEMPLATE...

Thanks for all help.

PS I have also tried **!important** and no joy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
body.single-doctor .qodef-post-info-category { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Must have a SPACE between elements declaration.

Comment: Nope....thanks for replying. I tried that and it didn't work....

Comment: Try to put `display: none !important;` with my suggestion (with space)